# How to pass a variable from outside the function to a firebase event

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, twilio

Below is my code running on nodeJS server, I am trying to [send an SMS message](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages) as soon as the `'child_added'` event is triggered

```
// Twilio Credentials
var accountSid = '<AccountSid>';
var authToken = '<authToken>';


var twilio = require("twilio");
var client = new twilio.RestClient(accountSid, authToken);

// TWILIO Function
client.messages.create({
    to: "+12432056980", // This need to be obtained from firebase
    from: "+14352058756",
    body: "Hey There! Good luck on the bar exam!"
}, function(err, message) {
    console.log(message.sid);
});
```

Below is the event that is triggered as soon as a child is added to [firebase database](https://firebase.google.com), I would like to call the TWILIO Function (shown above) as soon as as the below event is triggered and also pass it the mobile number variable from the below function.

```
ref.limitToFirst(1).on('child_added', function(snapshot) { // This function triggers the event when a new child is added
  var userDetails = snapshot.val();
  var mobileNumber = userDetails.mobileNumber;

  //*** I would like to call the TWILIO CODE  at this point and pass it the 'mobileNumber' parameter

});
```

Comment: Can you ellaborate a bit on what exactly you need done, I dont know how twilio works or what you mean by firebase. Passing the value is as simple as it gets with a parameter, I do not see the issue?

Comment: Where is the event handler located? Same file as the twilio require above?

Comment: @Dellirium I have simplified my question, Firebase is a realtime database from Google and Twilio offers developers to send SMS using their API.

Comment: @10100111001 Yes, the event handler is located in the same file as twilio require.

Comment: @kurrodu Is there an error you are receiving when you call the twilio functio? What is the exact problem you're having?

Comment: I tried to call the Twilio function inside the event handler, by passing `client` along with the `snapshot` parameter. I get an error:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'messages' of null

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the two operations are within the same file you can just wrap the `Twilio` call in a function and call it from within the `Firebase` operation like so...

```
function sendSMS(dest, msg) {
    client.messages.create({
        to: dest,
        from: "+14352058756",
        body: msg
    }, function(err, message) {
        console.log(message.sid);
    });
}

ref.limitToFirst(1).on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
  var userDetails = snapshot.val();
  var mobileNumber = userDetails.mobileNumber;

  sendSMS(mobileNumber, "Hey There! Good luck on the bar exam!");
});
```

If the `Twilio` operation is in a different file, you can export it and require where you use `Firebase`

```
//twiliofile.js
module.exports.sendSMS = function(dest, msg) {
    client.messages.create({
        to: dest,
        from: "+14352058756",
        body: msg
    }, function(err, message) {
        console.log(message.sid);
    });
}
```

-

```
//firebasefile.js
var sms = require('./twiliofile.js');

ref.limitToFirst(1).on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
  var userDetails = snapshot.val();
  var mobileNumber = userDetails.mobileNumber;

  sms.sendSMS(mobileNumber, "Hey There! Good luck on the bar exam!");
});
```

Comment: Hey m_callens, appreciate your help in the Twilio-tagged community. Can I send you a shirt to say thanks? Send an email to mspeir@twilio.com for details.